# making an "extreme" dialog gui for android

Tags: android, graphics, dialog, blur

i have seen Romain Guys work with swing programs and am really interested if someone could help me emulate this sort of graphics with a dialog on android. i am really confused as to how to change the background (ps. i did do hours of googling but was still confused on how to create a dialog that might look like the one posted in the link below)

if someone could guide me, i would be more than obliged.

thank you

URL to Dialog wanted to emulate:
[Curious Creature Dialog -- Extreme GUI: Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2007/08/01/blurred-background-for-dialogs-extreme-gui-makeover-2007/)

Comment: and that looks freakin sexy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the background blur you can use the WindowManager.LayoutParams, [This page](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/) has an example of just that.

The Dialog they show in the link you posted could be created using either a custom extension of a dialog, or a completely new activity with the theme set to tranclucent.

Comment: For future readers, it should be noted that the FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND feature was deprecated and no longer functions (creates a black background) as of API Level 14. Custom solutions are now need for the blurring.